Laravel Horizon Dashboard - Failed Jobs tab causing memory error
We have deployed Horizon in production, and the jobs themselves are being processed fine. However, when we load the Horizon dashboard and go to the failed jobs tab we get this issue.
The front end fires the /horizon/api/jobs/failed?starting_at=0 request every few seconds. This causes an error in the backend of:
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 139061374 bytes)
I can't find any pattern for when the issue happens. The number of failed jobs is very modest, and looking into the Horizon code it does not seem like it should be a heavy load on the server! This is the route/controller method that is causing the issue.
Route:
vendor/laravel/horizon/routes

Route::get('/jobs/failed', 'FailedJobsController@index')->name('horizon.failed-jobs.index');

Controller:
namespace Laravel\Horizon\Http\Controllers;
class FailedJobsController extends Controller

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $jobs = ! $request->query('tag')
                ? $this->paginate($request)
                : $this->paginateByTag($request, $request->query('tag'));

        $total = $request->query('tag')
                ? $this->tags->count('failed:'.$request->query('tag'))
                : $this->jobs->countFailed();

        return [
            'jobs' => $jobs,
            'total' => $total,
        ];
    }

The jobs themselves process fine without issues. It's just the horizon dashboard where we're having the problem.

what is $this->tags and $this->jobs?

That's inside the Horizon contoller that's part of the package, not my code. Have edited to make that clear.

than raise an issue on their github
